# Main Layout is set But Displaying in wrap content only

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]i create one layout  parent layout all are match parent But still displaying wrap contain only. I tried all layout set match parent but it is not display in full width how can solve that type of issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightyellow"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
    layout="@layout/header" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnSelectEventName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Header Layout file is.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/GreenColor"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_header_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_sidemenu"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_middle_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Header Name"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_medium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_header_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_search_home"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share xml code.

Comment: Show your `Xml` code.

Comment: maybe the layout container, but not the content...

Comment: you set the spinner weight, but the imageView to wrap_content.....that will not work. Also, you have set some margin values, maybe too big....

Comment: What is `android:id="@+id/rightLayout"`?

Comment: Also post included `Right Layout code`. What is it contains ?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs it is work well which is used other in lay out

Answer (score 1):

> Make changes to your `Layout` as below. Remove unnecessary `padding` and `margins` from that `Layout`. And give some `weight` to `ImageView` as well so it will work properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnSelectEventName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cahnges as u said but no any effect same as previously result getting

Comment: @MehulTank It should show in full screen with given background what ever you have given. It is working with the above code my side.

Comment: background is light yellow which is shown in image no any given white background

Comment: @MehulTank Then what your content should show in `center` of the `layout` ?

Comment: i want to display my contain in full screen as well width is given match parent and hight also given match parent but cant display in full screen